# Integration without complex analysis on rational-improper integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^6 + 1} \,\mathrm dx$$

Without **the use of complex-analysis.**

With complex analysis it is a very simple problem, how can this be done WITHOUT complex analysis?

Comment: Can you start with $x=\dfrac1y$?

Comment: Is the beta function a known thing?

Comment: Yes, I have experience

Comment: Why do you tag the question complex-analysis if you are asking for a solution without complex analysis?

Comment: @mrf, sorry, I didnt notice, I was typing multiple questions at once, and so didnt focus on tags too much. Feel free to remove it if you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\mathcal I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^6} \,\mathrm dx
$

$$\begin{align} 
I&=\frac{1}{2}\left[ \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-x^2+x^4)+x^2+(1-x^4)}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4)} \,\mathrm  dx \right]\tag{1}\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}  \,\mathrm dx
+ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^6}  \,\mathrm dx 
+ \color{grey}{\int_0^\infty \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx}\right] \tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac\pi2+ \frac\pi{6} +\color\grey{0} \right] \tag{3}\\
&\mathcal I=\frac{\pi}{3} \tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^6} \,\mathrm dx=\frac\pi3$$

---

$\text{ Explanation : }(3)$

$$
\small\color\grey{J=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx}
=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx
+\int_1^\infty \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx$$
Now substitute 
$\small\displaystyle x=\frac1t$ in second integral, To get

$$
\small\color\grey{J=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx}
=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx
-\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^2}{1-t^2+t^4} \,\mathrm  dt=\color\grey0$$

Comment: I can explain grey colored integral result if required

Comment: Great answer. Isnt the grey section from partial fractions?

Answer (score 3):

> *how can this be done WITHOUT complex analysis?*

$\quad$ All integrals of the form $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{(x^n+a^n)^m}dx~$ can be evaluated by substituting $x=at$ and $u=\dfrac1{t^n+1}$ , then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and lastly

employing Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to simplify the result.

Comment: Just curious--why do you denote that $x^{k-1}$ as opposed to $x^k$?

Comment: @anorton: Solve it, and the answer will come.

Comment: Ok, now I see. :)  I'm stuck, though, on using the reflection formula to simplify the last result that I get--I have something involving $\frac{\Gamma(k/n)\Gamma(m-k/n)}{\Gamma(m)}$.  If $m=1$ (like in the OP's case), Euler's reflection formula is easy to apply; however, in the general case, I don't see much hope.

Comment: @anorton: If *m* is an integer, use the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $x=\dfrac1y,$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^6}dx=\cdots=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^4}{1+x^6}dx$$

$$2I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x^4}{1+x^6}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+x^2)^2-2x^2}{1+x^6}dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2+x^4}dx-\frac23\int_0^\infty\frac{3x^2}{1+x^6}dx$$

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2+x^4}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1/x^2+1}{1/x^2-1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{1/x^2+1}{\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2-3}dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dz}{z^2-3}$$

$$=\frac1{2\sqrt3}\ln\frac{z-\sqrt3}{z+\sqrt3}|_{-\infty}^\infty=\frac1{2\sqrt3}\ln\frac{1-\sqrt3/z}{1+\sqrt3/z}|_{-\infty}^\infty=\ln1-\ln1=0$$

$$I_2=\int_0^\infty\frac{3x^2}{1+x^6}dx=\arctan(1+x^3)|_0^{\infty}=\frac\pi2-\frac\pi4=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: Ok, so I believe I've followed most of your calculations... the only part I don't understand is that if I substitute back in and solve, I get $I = \frac{-\pi}{12}$, while the answer should be $\frac{\pi}{3}$.  Perhaps the difficulty I'm having lies in the evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dz}{z^2-3}$...